# Crop a quad in existing texture_2D

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opengl

I have texture already rendered and I'm mapping a quad/rectangle on it. (Quad may be smaller or equal to total texture size)

Once the Quad is mapped, I want to remove the rest (what ever is drawn outside quad).

So far i can map quad and get my sub texture(not to be removed) however I'm unable to delete the remaining region(outside quad).

Following Images show the procedure;

1.Original Image

[image: Original Image]

2.Original Image with quad in red color

[image: Original Image with quad in red color]

3.Everything removed except quad. Texture after Cropping

[image: Everything removed except quad. Texture after Cropping]

Comment: No. I have mapped several textures on viewport. now i have to select a rectangular region over the rendered scene. Anything outside this rectangular region should be cropped(or turned black). 

I can successfully draw quad and take the rectangular region. But i cannot black out the rest(In image 3 the black region is cropped but i cannot do it in opengl). I tried to delete all textures but it still stays there.

Comment: It might be useful if you provide an (approximate) image of the result you want.

Comment: How you you render the quad? Usually, it is sufficient to adjust the texture coordinates. If you use shaders, you can implement a range check in the pixel shader.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have solved it using Nehe's [Lesson 3](http://nehe.gamedev.net/tutorial/adding_colour/13003/). I used

```
glColor3f(0.0f,0.0f,0.0f);             // Set The Color To Black
glBegin(GL_QUADS);                     // Start Drawing Quads
glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);         // Left And Up 1 Unit (Top Left)
glVertex3f( 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);         // Right And Up 1 Unit (Top Right)
glVertex3f( 1.0f,-1.0f, 0.0f);         // Right And Down One Unit(Bottom Right)
glVertex3f(-1.0f,-1.0f, 0.0f);         // Left And Down One Unit (Bottom Left)
glEnd();                               // Done Drawing A Quad`
```

to draw 4 quads of black color, to crop the region outside my selected region.

Thanks to Nehe.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you compute your texture coordinates in your code but there is not millions way to do it, so I'll give a solution for the three easiest way I have in mind :

1. You only have a vertex array containing the positions of your vertice for your quad, and use them to compute your texture coordinates. In that case, just modify the position of your vertice to your crop area before drawing.
2. You have a vertex array containing both the positions and texture coordinates (or two vertex arrays, one for each). You must change the area covered in both. For your specific use case I would advise to compute the texture coordinates from the vertice positions in the vetex shader for simplicity and efficiency.
3. You send your cropping area as a uniform to your fragment shader. This solution assumes you work in ortho space at the picture will always fill the screen. In that case, from the input vector position, you know where you are. With a simple if condition, you can check if you are out of boundaries. If so, set the pixel to black or use `discard` to cancel the drawing of the pixel. Conditions are time consuming so I would only advise this solution is you wish to set the cropped pixels to black. If you prefer to have them not displayed at all, the solution 1 is the fastest.